# Python attribute error in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to create some frames in Tkinter, that should be updated periodically.
Here is the code for on of them:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

class KopfFrame:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master,bg="tan")
        frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.ZeitLabel = Label(frame)
        self.ZeitLabel.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=NO,ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        self.ZeitLabel.configure(text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        # call this function again in 5 seconds
        #print(self)
        self.after(5000, self.refresh)

root = Tk()
K = KopfFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But, when I run it, I have the error:

```
AttributeError: KopfFrame instance has no attribute 'after'
```

I am pretty sure, that the way of calling is the problem. So if someone could help me, thaf I would either be thankful for a hint to a good tutorial for functions, classes an how to call an use them.

Comment: What did you expect `self.after()` to do? Your class does not define that method, perhaps something *else* has such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `self.after()`, with `self` being an instance of your `KopfFrame` class. That class does not have such a method defined.

Perhaps you wanted to call the [`Frame.after()` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) here. You'll need to store a reference to the `Frame` object you pass in first, then call `after` on *that*:

```
class KopfFrame:
    def __init__(self,master):
        # make frame an attribute on self
        self.frame = Frame(master, bg="tan")
        self.frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.ZeitLabel = Label(self.frame)
        self.ZeitLabel.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=NO,ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        self.ZeitLabel.configure(text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        # now you can reach the frame and call after on that:
        self.frame.after(5000, self.refresh)
```

What I changed:

- Instead of making `frame` only a local in the `KopfFrame.__init__` method, make it an attribute on `self`.
- Use the `self.frame` reference to the frame in `KopfFrame.refresh()` to access the `Frame.after()` method.

Comment: Now the  the Error is: global name 'frame' is not definied

Comment: @Puetong0815: corrected, I had forgotten to adjust one `frame` reference in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Yepp, in that way it works. Do You know some tutorials, that can explain me better that kind of problems? Or is this just learning by doing?

Comment: @Puetong0815 I'm sorry, it has been decades since I used Python tutorials, and I'm not in a position to recommend anything. Learn by doing is how I did it anyway. :-)